# What iterate mean in activemq source code

Tags: activemq-classic

I mean the iterate() func in org.apache.activemq.thread.Task, which have implements in Queue,Topic, etc.

I really can't understand what it mean and what's used for.

Can somebody explain it in an easily understood way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an internal interface in ActiveMQ, you shouldn't worry about it ;-)

This is just an abstraction about splitting a long job into smaller tasks: instead of using a thread for a long time, this interface allows to split a task between several iteration, each iteration using a thread for a short time.

Some "repeatable" task use this interface too: As this is an internal interface of the current implementation of ActiveMQ, there is not really strict rules about it.